# Vortex solution of Laplace equation (XY model)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, vortex, low-temperature-physics

The hamiltonian of XY model, which is closely connected with BKT - transition is following:

\begin{equation}
    H=\frac{J}{2} \int \text{d}^2 r \, \nabla \varphi \cdot \nabla \varphi, \quad \boldsymbol{r} = (x,\,y)^T 
\end{equation}

So the equation of motion is simply $\nabla^2\varphi=0$. In literature it is often said then, that there is a following solution:

\begin{equation}
    \varphi = \pm\, \text{Im} [\log(z-z_0)^n],\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}  
\end{equation}

Which is derived according to following boundary condition:

\begin{equation}
    \oint \nabla \varphi \cdot \text{d }\boldsymbol{r}=2 \pi n
\end{equation}

Here $z = x+iy$. My question is how can I get this solution in good faith. Of course, I can just check that it is the answer, but I'm interested in derivation.

Comment: It seems that you should find the Green function, which solves $\Delta G(r)=\delta(r)$. In 2D it is $\propto\ln(r)$. You can deal with complex plane $z=x+iy$, which is more suitable

Answer (score 1):

for $n=1$:

the boundary conditions you mentioned can be written as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla\times\nabla \varphi = 2\pi\hat{z}\delta^2({\bf r})
\end{eqnarray}

choosing:

\begin{equation}
\nabla \varphi = \nabla\times {\bf A}
\end{equation}

then, assuming the gauge fix condition $\nabla\cdot {\bf A} = 0$ :

\begin{equation}
-\nabla^2 {\bf A} =  2\pi\hat{z}\delta^2({\bf r})
\end{equation}

in which ${\bf r} = (x,y)$, taking ${\bf A} = \hat{z}\psi$ (which guarantees the gauge fix condition):

\begin{equation}
\nabla^2\psi = -2\pi\delta^2({\bf r})
\end{equation}

which results in:

\begin{equation}
\psi = -\log |{{\bf r}\over a}| 
\end{equation}

From here backwards now you can solve for $\varphi$ which I think you can do using transformation to complex plane in order to get exactly what you are looking for. Look into https://a.co/d/jewfETD , chapter 8.